# VBA Error Handler Fails for "For Each __ in __" While Referencing ActiveX Controls: Run-time Error 438

Tags: vba, foreach, error-handling, runtime-error, activex

I have a worksheet full of ActiveX controls. I know they're buggy on Worksheets so this is the function I've implemented to reset the controls and keep their behavior in check.

The problem is that the Error handler doesn't catch a Run-time Error 438 that occurs because of an attempt to access the auto-size property of a ListBox (List Boxes don't have an auto-size property, hence the run-time 438 error).

```
    Public Sub RefreshCtrlSheet(Optional ByRef HiddenElements As Variant)

    'This sub refreshes ActiveX Objects on the Ctrl Sheet
    Dim objX As Object          'Holds OLEObjects from Control Sheet
    Dim tempWidth As Double     'Store size of object to restore
    Dim tempHeight As Double    'after resetting
    Dim tempLeft As Double
    Dim tempTop As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheet1

        'Error Handler
        On Error GoTo NotTheObjsUrLooking4

        For Each objX In .OLEObjects

            'If Name has Button in it
            If InStr(objX.Name, "Button") > 0 Then

                'Implement different button sizes
                If objX.Name = "LoadDataButton" Then
                    tempHeight = 24.75
                    tempWidth = 24.75
                Else
                    tempHeight = 30
                    tempWidth = 80
                End If

            Else
                tempHeight = objX.Height
                tempWidth = objX.Width
            End If

            'Check to see if elements should be hidden
            If Not IsMissing(HiddenElements) Then
                For i = 1 To UBound(HiddenElements)
                    If InStr(objX.Name, HiddenElements(i)) Then
                        objX.Visible = False
                    End If
                Next i
            End If

            tempLeft = objX.Left
            tempTop = objX.Top

            'Autosize to refresh shingking controls (ActiveX Bug)
            objX.object.AutoSize = True '----------------------RUNTIME ERROR HERE!
            objX.object.AutoSize = False
            objX.Width = tempWidth
            objX.Height = tempHeight
            objX.Left = tempLeft
            objX.Top = tempTop

NotTheObjsUrLooking4: '----------------------------THIS WORKS EVERY OTHER ERROR
        Next objX

    On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

It started having issues when I added a new ActiveX ListBox, which is weird because I had another one already, which never had issues.

Thanks for any help anyone is able to offer!

**Edit:**

Thanks Mat's that's it.

The new code works with:

```
...
'Error Handler
On Error GoTo CleanFail
...

'Other code

...
NotTheObjsUrLooking4:
      Next objX
   End With 
   On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

CleanFail:
   Err.Clear
   Resume NotTheObjsUrLooking4
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how error-handling works in VBA.

Yes, it's a *jump*, but it's a jump *to an error-handling subroutine*. `NotTheObjsUrLooking4` isn't a subroutine, it's just a "continue" label that's part of your control flow / logic.

Make a `CleanFail` label:

```
    ...
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Err.Clear
    Resume NotTheObjsUrLooking4
End Sub
```

And then adjust your `On Error` statement to jump to `CleanFail` instead:

```
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
```

That will make execution jump out of the loop and into that error-handling subroutine, which clears the error and basically says *these are not the <s>droids</s> objects you're looking for*... and resumes to the next iteration.

Remove `On Error GoTo 0`, you don't need it.

Comment: Why is it that you don't need "On Error GoTo 0"? I always though you needed to reset the Error behavior, or does Resume within the error handler do that for you?

Comment: @BryanHarper you only need `GoTo 0` to "reset error handling" (typically after setting `On Error Resume Next`) - `On Error GoTo` jumps are always procedure-local, so there's nothing to reset after cleanly handling a runtime error; the `Resume` keyword resets error state (proof: try calling `Resume` without being in an error state ;-)